# Web3 and Angular 11 broken dependencies

Tags: angular, web3js

I'm trying to create Ethereum dapp with Angular.
I was following that article:
https://medium.com/blockchain-developer/learn-how-to-create-your-own-dapp-with-angular-9-part-iv-truffle-7704dc4269ab
However, when I added web3 to app with `npm install --save web3`,
and called it in code, I got following issues:

```
Error: ./node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

Error: ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/cipher-base'

Error: ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/keccak.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/keccak/lib/api'

Error: ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/shake.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/szymon/dev/dapp/node_modules/keccak/lib/api'
```

What should I do?
Web3 is called like this:

```
let Web3 = require('web3');
export class TransferService {
    constructor() {   
      if (typeof window.web3 !== undefined) {
        this.web3 = window.web3.currentProvider;
      } else {
        this.web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      }
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      this.enable = this.enableMetaMaskAccount();
      }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to call `web3` in the Angular code?

Comment: Look at original post, it was edited.

Comment: if you're calling it from the browser try `import Web3 from 'web3';` instead of  `let Web3 = require('web3');`

Comment: Using `import` in the case of a browser is a good point. However  if `web3` is a pure JavaScript library it might be not enough to use `import`. The JavaScript files need to be listed in `angular.json` in `architect`->`build`->`scripts[]` array.

Comment: Using `import` instead of `require` doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Did you try to add the JavaScript file paths to the `scripts[]` in `angular.json` as suggested above?

Comment: not sure which files needs to be added

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by uninstalling web3 and reinstalling version 1.2.11

Step 1: npm uninstall web3

Step 2: npm install web3@1.2.11

I am not sure if this will have other consequences but it worked for me after alot of frustration!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue in my Angular 11 application and I was able to solve it using this method. Thanks to @Zakoff, for supply this version of web3.

Step 1.

> npm uninstall web3

Step 2.

> npm install web3@1.2.11

Step 3. update **package.json** with the words in single quotes shown in your  error. In your case, 'crypto', 'https', 'http', 'os', and 'stream'.

update package.json like this immediately after dev dependencies:

```
"browser": {
"crypto": false,
"https": false,
"http": false,
"os": false,
"stream": false
}
```

Your **package.json** should look like this.
[image: screenshot of my package.sjon]